# Can't draw dynamic pie chart

Tags: python, graph, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a pie chart with Turtle that is dynamic and can react to different sets of data it is provided with, but for some reason it is not drawing the lines that make the segments.

Would someone be able to help identify the problem in my code so that it will execute `segment()` as I intended?

```
chart_title = 'Tourism GDP by States/Territories in Australia'
segment_labels = ['QLD', 'VIC', 'NSW', 'SA', 'WA', 'TAS', 'NT', 'ACT']
percentages = [0.24, 0.22, 0.328, 0.06, 0.082, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02]

from turtle import *

radius = 200


penup()
forward(radius)
left(90)
pendown()
color('palegreen')
begin_fill()
circle(radius)
end_fill()
home()
right(90)
color('black')

def segment(percentages):
    for _ in percentages[:]:
        radius=200
        percent_to_heading=((percentages*100)/360)*100
        setheading(percent_to_heading)
        pendown()
        forward(radius)
        penup()
        home()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your for loop should probably look more like this:

```
for percent in percentages:
```

The percent_to_heading variable is not the value you want. Since each element in the list of percentages is the percent of the circle you want the segment to take up, you should multiply the current element by 360.

```
percent_to_heading = percent * 360
```

Finally, you need to create a rolling percent variable that will have the sum of the current angle and all the angles before it. Otherwise the segments would overlap each other. The final function should look simlar to this:

```
def segment(percentages):
    rollingPercent = 0
    radius=200
    for percent in percentages:
        segment = percent * 360
        rollingPercent += segment
        setheading(rollingPercent)
        pendown()
        forward(radius)
        penup()
        home()
```